# Reaching UI Elements created by code at different class

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm creating UICollectionViewCells programmatically. That cell has a Content View (I'm using it only like a decorative frame). Inside that view I create UILabel, UIImageView and another UILabel. All set ups are done when cell is initialized. All works perfect

At ViewController I want to reach that UI Components at method:
CellForItemAt
What will be the best way to do that? Now im working with viewTags to reach particular component, but maybe there is better way?

I need to reach it to fill it with data from CoreData

BR
iMat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have created your `UICollectionViewCell's` UI programmatically, you can have those UI elements as public variable in your `UICollectionViewCell`.

And Create a public method to set the data into your `CustomCell`'s UI elements as like below.

```
class CustomCell:UICollectionViewCell{

    var imageView:UIImageView!
    var label1:UILabel!
    var label2:UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        //Initialize your imageView,label1 and label2
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func set(_ text1:String?, text2:String?, image:UIImage?){

        imageView.image = image
        label1.text = text1
        label2.text = text2
    }
}
```

In your `cellForItemAt` function pass your data to your custom cell as like below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourCustomCellID", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.set("1", text2: "2", image: yourImage)

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass

```
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var item: Item? 
    ...
    func setUI() {
        label.text = item.someProperty
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You can downcast your cell as your subclass when you dequeued it

```
cell as! MyCell
```

... then you have access to subclass's methods, variables, etc.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.item = array[indexPath.row]
    cell.setUI()
    ...
    return cell
}
```